# Possible way to find how long system call takes?

Tags: c++, linux, time, system

Is there any way to find early time of system calls .How long will the system calls takes for example:

```
 system(smbtree);
```

**How can i find how long will above system call takes.so that i can display waiting time?**

I am able to calculating execution time using `time()` but is there any way to find early so that i can put count down or waiting time?

Comment: this is like seeing the future. You can't know how long X will take before X is executed, X operation has to communicate the progress back to be able to display a accurate progress.

Comment: As soon as we've solved the Halting Problem, we should be able to write a function that can do this too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't.**

There is simply no way to know ahead of time how long some arbitrary shell call will take to complete. Not only is every call different, but different computers running different numbers of processes under different operating systems on different processors in different temperatures will take different amounts of time to perform the task.

Naively, the best you can do is to come up with some vague estimation based on empirical testing (like, "my shell script usually takes around five seconds to run wherever I've tested it") and hope that's close enough in reality. Make sure to write your code to support going over and/or changing that estimation, as it often will.

A proper solution will involve the third-party process itself providing status information directly to the calling process as it progresses.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to calculate execution time ahead of time first since how long it takes will be dependent on the machine it is run on.

Comment: It'll depend on a lot more than that.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition So how is what I said wrong?  Just because it is dependent on more than that doesn't make the fact that the machine it is run on is one of the factors any less true.

Comment: You can't calculate the time, since you can't know all the internals that affect the time spent. You can measure a bunch and then take the average, but even then that's only an average. What if your thread is preempted during the call (which is a prime spot for preemption)?